# MYSQL - selecting latest row from a join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a regular join but select the latest entry from the history_items table using a where clause.

```
SELECT h.history_id,
   Date_format(From_unixtime(h.timestamp), '%d %m %Y') AS 'date',
   h.status,
   h.product_id,
   p.serial_number,
   p.product_name,
   p.site_name,
   p.site_postcode,
   Date_format(From_unixtime(i.timestamp), '%d %m %Y') AS 'last_update',
   i.feedback
FROM   history h
   LEFT JOIN products p
          ON h.product_id = p.product_id
   LEFT JOIN history_items i
          ON h.history_id = i.history_id
WHERE  i.timestamp = (SELECT Max(i.timestamp)
                  FROM   history_items)
GROUP  BY i.history_id
ORDER  BY h.timestamp DESC
```

I am selecting Max(i.timestamp) - this is still not returning the latest entry from the history_items table.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
WHERE  i.timestamp = (SELECT Max(i.timestamp)
              FROM   history_items)
```

The `i` should not be there, it should be `Max(timestamp)` not `Max(i.timestamp)`.

Else Mysql will really select the value of the `i.timestamp` row. So if your timestamp is `1` it will evaluate to this:

```
WHERE 1 =(SELECT Max(1) FROM hsitory_items)
```

Which basically will be

```
WHERE i.timestamp = i.timestamp
```

I bet you get the idea now. That's why all rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are anyways sorting on `timestamp` saying `ORDER BY h.timestamp DESC` you actually don't need the below pointed `WHERE` condition at all. Also the subquery in below pointed code is wrongly referring the column as already mentioned in other answer

```
WHERE  i.timestamp = (SELECT Max(i.timestamp)
                  FROM   history_items)
```

Comment: Sorry if I ask a stupid question now. But why should he not need the subquery? `h.timestamp` has not do have anything to do with `i.timestamp`. What do i get wrong ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, cause that's unnecessary since OP anyway doing `WHERE  i.timestamp = (SELECT Max(i.timestamp) ...` and then again `order by ...` well though absolutely not sure but kind a guess that it won't be needed

Comment: If I had to guess I would agree with you. But it is really hard to tell from the question. Since there could be multiple history's (`h`) which share the same entry(`i`). But yes, you are most probably right. Thank you for explaining.